# Jupyter notebook can't open on my mac

Tags: python, anaconda

```
[I 03:22:51.647 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/?token=a97ddfd10231bf52d5bf2235602e66dd51b7ded16e553341
[I 03:22:51.647 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 03:22:51.651 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=a97ddfd10231bf52d5bf2235602e66dd51b7ded16e553341
0:97: execution error: "http://localhost:8889/tree?token=d884ffa1365d5b78c031cdaf62f671aaba08b0b25d3eaeb6" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)
```

Ωåœœ

My mac's version is Sierra,is that the problem? How can i fix it..

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5408 and https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438

Comment: Update your software; the bug was fixed in a later beta of Sierra.

Comment: Just copy & paste the url on your browser. I have the same problem with my Mac Jupyter which is use for work at home. I didn't got this problem with Windows 10 yet. :(

Comment: Is it true? @AryaMcCarthy will check it then.

Comment: Hi~ do you mean I just need to update my Anaconda-Navigator ?

Comment: I found this solution~but  I don't know where to vim it

his issue due to the newest Mac OSX 10.12.5 upgrade. Please follow these steps to fix it:

Generate jupyter config if you don't have it:
jupyter notebook --generate-config
Use vim to open that config file and add Google chrome value in:
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'chrome' (Make sure to take out the # comment sign)